# "consumers may not trust producers for (??) enforcing the property"

Tags: grammar

Here's an example sentence:

> "consumers may not trust producers *for* enforcing the property"

Should it really be "*for*" there on the middle? Or should it be some other word?

Comment: Trust someone **to** do something.

Comment: *"consumers may not trust producers to enforcing the property"*? Sounds weird with the *enforcing* afterwards, no?

Comment: actually, "consumers may not trust producers **to enforce** the property"?. but as I'm not sure, I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: This error may be influenced by this more common formation: "[The web’s best brands trust us for their online video needs](http://www.viddler.com/)." Still, in that case it should be "for _enforcement_ of the property," which is wordier than "to enforce the property."

Comment: aa. right. interesting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be "*consumers may not trust producers to enforce the property.*"

Comment: What does it mean to enforce a property? Although your sentence is grammatically well-formed, I'm not sure it actually means anything in English.

Comment: @MArcin - That should be directed at the OP. Enforcing a property can have specific meeting in some contexts. I can think of this meaning something in programming, as in enforcing the property of a class.

Comment: Perhaps, but even then that would be an unusual usage.